# Restricting access by IP on Nginx with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

Denying access to a path on Nginx with Laravel works but the visited page breaks on the allowed IP address. What am I doing wrong?

I have been using the following snippet to block access to http://some.url/admin (and http://some.url/admin/login). Works for other purposes, like Wordpress.

```
# Restrict administrative access
location /admin/ {
  allow x.x.x.x;
  deny all;
}
```

I get an 403 error when visiting from a non-allowed IP, which is good. 
But I get an 404 error when visiting from the allowed IP.

```
2017/02/20 18:40:36 [error] 2663#2663: *325 "/var/www/some-website/html/public/admin/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server: some.website, request: "GET /admin/ HTTP/2.0", host: "some.website"
```

I suspect something goes wrong with the routes in my Laravel application.

A lot of trial and error, searching on the web and StackOverflow gave me no successful answers. Thanks in advance!

PS. This is my first post. If I am doing something wrong please tell me.

Comment: I believe you cannot do this thing with laravel, since `admin` is not a file (like in Wordpress), its more like a query variable.

Comment: Can you  add this in the block? `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`

Comment: @geckob Adding this line (`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`) to the location block solved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: @geckob Could you bump your comment to an answer?

Comment: Will do once on laptop. Please vote up and accept later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. Point the location back to the root by adding this to the location block:

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`